Setting 3d cursor in 3d space
I would like to learn how to set the 3d cursor in 3d space. I don't mean select vertices and set cursor to selected. When using the spin tool, I can kind of use the x, y, z offset and get something decent. My question is more about how to use snapping in Blend 4.0 exactly to set 3d cursor to a point in the perspective view.

You can set the cursor position in the N panel under View > 3D Cursor.
